# Oil tank level WITHOUT access to the top of the tank (cannot use a gauge, dip stick, etc)

Tags: temperature

I recently purchased a split level house with a heating oil tank that is underneath the lower half of the stairs in a cabinet. Because it is in a cabinet, there is no way to access to top of the tank. It's completely framed in. Is there a reliable way I can tell how much oil is left? (besides tapping on the side)

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: @Robert Cartaino This is not an exact duplicate of a previous question due to the unique location limitations: stable temperature and total lack of access to the top. None of the answers for the other question can be applied here.

Comment: @Stan I know not all of the answers on the other question are applicable, but why not this one? https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/3661/15

Comment: @Mooseman This post requested a workaround to "tapping on the side" which is reasonable. None of the other answers to the "duplicate" relate to this situation. The only similar part is the object in question. No?

Comment: @Stan Why not the magnet one? The question is almost identical, it just adds a couple stipulations as to why answers there wouldn't work here.